# How do i extract response value of a promise.all call (ReactJS multiple endpoints)

Tags: reactjs, promise

```
const handleJson = (res) => res.json();

const responses = await Promise.all([
      fetch(`${API_URL}/task1/get/${Id}`, options).then(handleJson),
      fetch(`${API_URL}/task2`, options).then(handleJson),
    ]);
```

In this sample i am calling two api endpoints with promise. The response has two response objects. The response is a plaintext and not in json format.

This issue i am facing is, i am not able to get the response object value.

How do i get the value of both the apis from the response object in to this?

```
const [data1, data2] = responses;
```

Comment: so you are not getting that json?

Comment: @NishargShah the response of the api is in plaintext and not in json format. The api returns an enrypted string (a token) in plaintext.
ex: YWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuc2VzYW1l

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the nice example for you

```js
(async () => {
    const res = await Promise.all([
        await fetch("https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random").then(res => res.json()),
        await fetch("https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random").then(res => res.json()),
    ])
    console.log(res);
})();
```

Comment: I will give it a try. What is the best way to extract the values of both responses?

Comment: `const [data1, data2] = responses;` like you done it, its best way

Comment: I am able to get the response objects but not able to extract the value.

Comment: This is the log i see

```
Response {type: "cors", url: "http://localhost:5000/task1", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}
```

In the network tab i can see the plain text, but on the console i don't see it.

Comment: please add await before `fetch`

Comment: you can run my code by clicking on `run code snippet`

Comment: Yes i did that. The problem is the response is not in json format. 
Does it matter? 

response comes like this 
yj8XYTprFJ8O20+4Op7Cpze76Cgb

Comment: it's up to API, what data you are getting from the API, if API gives you a simple string then converting into JSON its not matters